# Defining custom items in the contextMenu for rhandsontable in R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I am trying to define custom items in the contextMenu for rhandsontable in R, following the [Handsontable documentation](https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/). However, I am encountering an error. Here's the code I have tried:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(magrittr)

rhandsontable(iris) %>% hot_table(contextMenu = list(items = list('col_left', 'col_right')))
```

This code produces the following error:

```
Error in !is.null(contextMenu) && contextMenu : 
  invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
```

I found a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/76) that may provide some insight, but I am still unable to resolve the problem. How can I correctly define custom items in the contextMenu for rhandsontable?

---

**Edit:**
For context, I am using this script in Shiny. Perhaps we can directly manipulate the contextMenu via some javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a mouse and the right-click does not work on my pad, so I can't try. I would try:

```r
rhandsontable(iris, useTypes = FALSE) %>% 
  hot_context_menu(customOpts = list(items = list("col_left", "col_right")))
```

or

```r
hot <- rhandsontable(iris, useTypes = FALSE)
hot$x$contextMenu = list(items = list("col_left", "col_right"))
```

## EDIT

My pad works sometimes, I have been able to check and the second code works.